# Opencv filter2D

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv in order to implement potential fields for a game system.

I have a cv::mat of map size and I seed it with data describing how vulnerable my units are. The matrix is using 32 bit integers and the values range from 0 to about 1200.

I then use cv::filter2D in order to find the best position for building a trurret.

```
int kernelSize = (turretRange * 2) + 1;
cv::Mat circleKernel = cv::Mat( kernelSize, kernelSize, __potentialDataType, cv::Scalar::all(0) );
cv::circle(circleKernel, cv::Point(turretRange + 1, turretRange + 1), turretRange, 1, -1, 8 );
cv::filter2D( vulnerabilityMap, buildMap, -1, circleKernel, cv::Point(-1,-1) );
```

I then calculate the min and max value positions of the buildMap, where max should give me the best position for my turret.

```
double min2, max2;
cv::Point min_loc2, max_loc2;
cv::minMaxLoc(buildMap, &min2, &max2, &min_loc2, &max_loc2 );
```

What happens is that I get the optimal position in x while the y is turretRange short.

> That is, the max_loc2 is (optimal x, optimal y - turretRange)

Any hint on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.